# How can I list EPSG supported by ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr2ogr

I am trying to discover whether `ogr2ogr` is not supporting https://epsg.io/7710 at all or have I bungled parameter describing input data `ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:7710`)

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: @IanTurton `ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: crs not found
ERROR 1: Failed to process SRS definition: EPSG:7710` on `ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:7710 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -f 'ESRI Shapefile' outfile.shp Bexley.gml`

Answer (score 1):

No software supports EPSG:7710 as a coordinate reference system because it is not included in the EPSG database. Why do you believe that such exists? The only thing with code 7710 in the EPSG database is the ninth version of the tranformation from OSGB36 to WGS 84 https://epsg.org/transformation_7710/OSGB36-to-WGS-84-9.html?

If you transform data from EPSG:4277 into EPSG:4326 then GDAL (or rather the Proj library) will use the transformation EPSG:7710. It can be tested with projinfo

```
projinfo -s epsg:4277 -t epsg:4326

Operation No. 1:

DERIVED_FROM(EPSG):7710, OSGB36 to WGS 84 (9), 1.0 m, United Kingdom (UK) - offshore to boundary of UKCS within 49┬░45'N to 61┬░N and 9┬░W to 2┬░E; onshore Great Britain (England, Wales and Scotland). Isle of Man onshore.
...
```

Comment: And your data is probably in epsg:27700 anyway

Comment: @IanTurton It seemed so (shows in this way in QGIS), but `ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:27700 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -f "GeoJSON" Barnet.geojson Barnet.gml` outputs some broken Geojson with completely insane coordinates - just with `"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },` in header

Comment: Could you show one pair of the input coordinates and the insane output coordinates?

Comment: GeoJSON should be in EPSG:4326 not 3857